# Laravel - Merge multiple arrays into one object

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have this PHP code using Laravel 5.6:

```
$action = [
    [
        "name" => "action",
        "value" => "DepositMoney"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "coins",
        "type" => "number",
        "value" => "534"
    ]
];

return collect($action)->map(function($item, $key) {
    return [
        $item['name'] => $item['value']
    ];
});
```

which produces:

```
[
  {
    "action": "DepositMoney"
  },
  {
    "coins": "534"
  }
]
```

How do I make it so I can merge those together and produce this instead (using something from here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#available-methods):

```
[
    "action" => "DepositMoney",
    "coins" => "534"
]
```

Thanks. This is for `form_params` on Guzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `reduce()` function, to create a single value from multiple elements of an array. Documentation is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-reduce

I would suggesting trying this (I didn't test it, but you get the idea, and should be able to understand how to use `reduce` from this example):

```
return collect($action)->map(function($item, $key) {
    return [
        $item['name'] => $item['value']
    ];
})->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
        $carry[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $carry;
});
```

Comment: Note: there are equivalent functions in PHP (no Laravel required): `array_map()` and `array_reduce()`.

Comment: Ah man i tried reduce but I guess I didn't get it right. Anyway -- thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, run `collapse()` method on the result as follows:

```
return collect($action)->map(function($item, $key) {
    return [
        $item['name'] => $item['value']
    ];
})->collapse();

//Gives you:

{
  "action": "DepositMoney",
  "coins": "534"
}
```

See [Method Collapse](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-collapse) Otherwise you can use other array helper e.g [array_collapse](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-collapse) functions:

```
return array_collapse(array_map(function($item) {
        return [
            $item['name'] => $item['value']
        ];
   }, $action));
```